# Redundant ModelName in CakePHP find Results

Tags: arrays, json, cakephp

I am trying to get rid of the redundant model names in the results array returned by the find method in CakePHP. As it is now, if I were to do something like $results = $this->Model->find('all'), I would have to access a result field by $results[Model][fieldName] instead of $results[fieldName].

I understand that having the model name in the array has benefits but I am trying to build an api so I need to json encode the array. With the model name included I get something hideous like:

```
[{"Model":{"field":"blah","field":"blah"}},{"Model":{"field":"blah","field":"blah"}}]
```

I want something more elegant like:

```
[{"field":"blah","field":"blah"},{"field":"blah","field":"blah"}]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In your controller, instead of serializing the results of the find, serialise a level deeper.

Assuming CakePHP 2:

```
$things = $this->Thing->find('all');
$things = Set::extract('/Thing/.', $things);
```

Now your results should be free of the extra level in your JSON.

The alternative, lengthy way of doing it is to `for loop` over the results:

```
foreach ($things as $k => &$v) {
    $v = $v['Thing']
}
```

After that, your $things will have removed the extra level of keys.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I knew I could use a foreach loop but I was looking for something more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

For later versions of Cake, use $things = Set::extract($things, '{n}.Thing');